# Definitive list of all available CustomProperties for Series and DataPoint in MSChart

Tags: .net, mschart

I am working with the .NET 3.5 MSChart controls and from time to time I find that I need to add custom properties to either the Series or DataPoints.

For example:

```
Series series = new Series();
series["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";

DataPoint point = new DataPoint();
point["Exploded"] = "true"
point["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
```

All of the custom properties I use I have found about from the Web Samples project provided by Microsoft, sometimes from the source given in the samples, sometimes by opening the project up and finding the source manually.

My question is this, is there anywhere I can view the entire list of all available custom properties for reference purposes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The list is now maintained on MSDN at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456764.aspx

Comment: Link is outdated.

Answer (score 6):

MSChart is really the original Dundas Chart tool. Dundas has a [listing of all custom attributes](http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/webchart2005/CustomAttributes_All.html). Since they don't support Dundas Charts anymore, that link may die eventually. As of this date it is still valid.

Comment: I had to remove the accepted answer and give it to Phong since as you say the Dundas reference may not last forever. I would expect the Microsoft reference to exist as long as the control does, hence Phong's answer is 'more correct'.

Comment: Also the Dundas code is slightly different from the ASP.NET Charts, but the documentation is better on the Dundas website

Comment: That was a great source but now the link indeed has died :-(

Comment: Long live [waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160710110617/http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/webchart2005/CustomAttributes_All.html)