# Control the width of the column bar in a chart c#

Tags: c#, mschart

I am using a MS chart for displaying some information and i have to show different charts when the user clicks a bar. All that works totally fine. but the width is totally out of my control. It looks really weird. I tried to adjust it using :

```
 series["PointWidth"] = pointWidth.ToString();
```

But if the bars are placed far from each other. They widen drastically making it look very worse. Is there a way i can provide a constant width for all the bars?

And also how can i calculate the width of the x axis plane. Since the Width should be dynamic as per the number of bar. I would have to calculate it...any help ????

Answer (score 2):

```
Chart1.Series[0]("PixelPointWidth") = 2
```

Comment: How can i know the width of the x-axis?

Comment: you didn't ask about x-axis width initially. should open a new question rather than unaccept answer and ask new question `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LineWidth` is the line width of the axis and `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval` sets the intervals between the points on the x axis

Comment: did any of this help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Series.ForEach(s => s["PixelPointWidth"] = "50" );
```

Full list of [CustomProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294161/definitive-list-of-all-available-customproperties-for-series-and-datapoint-in-ms)